# CSS: Mobile menu submenu issue

Tags: html, css, menu

I have created a mobile menu.
Now I need to create a submenu in that menu.
There are two problems that occur while clicking the link to open the submenu.

1. The submenu opens behind the 1st level menu and should push the first level down.
2. If I "click" (how do you call it on a phone?) the link that opens a submenu it directly goes to the page, obvious but I have created menus that are mouse over for desktop and on a mobile device I was able to click the menu item twice so I could open the submenu.

Here is the HTML output!

```
<div class="menu-head-menu-container open">
    <ul id="menu-head-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-47">
                <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-50">
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-29">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for the submenu.

```
menu-head-menu-container > ul > li > ul {
    display:block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px 0 0 -10px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

This is the css from the 1st level menu items:

```
.menu-head-menu-container > ul > li {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    background: #006185;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 6px 0 0 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

I don't really see why the subpage won't be visible.

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i correctly understand, you can use something like this :

```
<div class="menu-head-menu-container open">
    <ul id="menu-head-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">click
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-47">123</li>
                <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-50">123</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-29">123</li>
    </ul>
</div>

$("#menu-head-menu li").click(function(){
    $(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
});

#menu-head-menu ul{
  display: none;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0c5r1k5/)

Comment: So close.. but the menu is for a mobile version. I have created the desktop version so this doesn't work for me. I have to find another way. nice pull tho! Is there any way it's possible to do with CSS?

Comment: Got it working using your way. Thank you. I just needed to read up on the use of `@media` queries.